# NHibernate: How to get mapped values?

Tags: nhibernate

Suppose I have a class Customer that is mapped to the database and everything is a-ok.

Now suppose that I want to retrieve - in my application - the column name that NH knows Customer.FirstName maps to.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the database field name through `NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration`:

```
// cfg is NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration
// You will have to provide the complete namespace for Customer
var persistentClass = cfg.GetClassMapping(typeof(Customer));
var property = persistentClass.GetProperty("FirstName");
var columnIterator = property.ColumnIterator;
```

The `ColumnIterator` property returns `IEnumerable<NHibernate.Mapping.ISelectable>`. In almost all cases properties are mapped to a single column so the column name can be found using `property.ColumnInterator.ElementAt(0).Text`.

Comment: I might be mistaken on this but I believe that it is also possible by querying some of the methods on the persister for the type.  You can get the persister from the factory

Comment: You can get a lot of info about the object from the persister but I could not find a way to access the database column name. It's a complex API so I might have missed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that that's doable.

I believe your best bet would be to use .xml files to do the mapping, package them together with the application and read the contents at runtime. I am not aware of an API which allows you to query hibernate annotations (pardon the Java lingo) at runtime, and that's what you would need.

Update:
Judging by Jamie's solution, NHibernate and Hibernate have different APIs, because the Hibernate [org.hibernate.Hibernate](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html) class provides no way to access a "configuration" property.